# WCF sometimes return 401

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, authentication, soap

Since we migrated a few websites from Windows Server a 2008 R2 to a Windows Server 2012, one website sometimes gets an error 401 from the WCF service it's calling on the same server. This can be working for ~1-2 days to ~1h before it fails. This seems only to happen once, after that it works again for X amount of time.

The problem seems to be isolated only to this website, there are a few others that are on another server calling this WCF service with no problem after the migration.

Both sites are on the same server but on different sites and appPools.

IIS log:

```
[DATE1] 12:03:40 [IP1] POST ServiceName.asmx - [PORT1]- [IP2] - - 401 0 0 0
[DATE1] 12:03:40 [IP1] POST ServiceName.asmx - [PORT1] - [IP2] - - 401 1 3221225581 0
```

Error from the website:

> ServiceName / ProcessData - DataAccess FunctionName- Message: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. StackTrace:

Config:

The website uses a domain account to access the WCF service which uses authentication mode windows.

Website binding

```
<binding name="ReportSummaryFacadeSoap" 
         closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
         maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" 
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
         transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
             maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
             maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>          
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">            
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                     proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                   algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
</binding>
```

I hope someone can shed light on this.

With kind regards

Patric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was thanks to the Hyper-V load balancing, that was not correctly configurated. Where the config for the persistent of the session was a bit low, so when it started to make a call to first machine and a few calls later it switched to the second machine in the load balancing, which resulted in a 401 respons.